# How can I solve "Non-static method xxx::xxxx() should not be called statically"

Tags: php, static-methods

I have a php file with the code below, I receive the error:

Strict Standards: Non-static method LinkCore::getImageLink() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in....

But if I change this line:

```
$product_image = Link::getImageLink($product->link_rewrite[1], (int)$images[0]['id_image'], 'large_default');
```

with

```
$product_image = Link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite[1], (int)$images[0]['id_image'], 'large_default');
```

I get

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in /xxx/xxx/public_html/modules/supplierreports/HTMLTemplateCustomPdf.php on line 44

And if I declare all functions with "public static", I get the error "Fatal error: Cannot make non static method HTMLTemplateCore::getContent() static in class HTMLTemplateCustomPdf in"

So what can I do to solve this issue??

```
<?php
class HTMLTemplateCustomPdf extends HTMLTemplate
{
public $supplier;
public function __construct($supplier_order, $smarty)
{
    //print_r($supplier_order);
            $this->supplier_order = $supplier_order;
            $this->supplier = new Supplier((int)$this->supplier_order->id_supplier);
            //$this->supplier_orders = $this->supplier_order->orders
    $this->smarty = $smarty;

            // header informations
            $id_lang = Context::getContext()->language->id;
            $this->title = HTMLTemplateCustomPdf::l('Supplier ').' : '.$this->supplier->name;

    // footer informations
    $this->shop = new Shop(Context::getContext()->shop->id);
}
/**
 * Returns the template's HTML content
 * @return string HTML content
 */
public function getContent()
{
            $order_products = array();
            $order_customers = array();

            if(count($this->supplier_order->orders)){
                foreach($this->supplier_order->orders as $order)
                {
                    //echo $order['id_product'];

                    $product = new Product($order['id_product']);

                    $customer = new Customer((int)$order['id_customer']);

                    $images = Image::getImages(1, (int)$order['id_product']);

                    $order_customers[(int)$order['id_customer']] = array('customer' => $customer);

                    if((int)$images[0]['id_image'])
                    {
                        $product_image = Link::getImageLink($product->link_rewrite[1], (int)$images[0]['id_image'], 'large_default');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $product_image = Link::getImageLink($product->link_rewrite[1], 'en');
                    }

                    $order_products[(int)$order['id_customer']][] = array('customer' => $customer, 'product' => $product, 'product_quantity' => $order['quantity'], 'product_image' => $product_image);
                    //$order_products[(int)$order['id_customer']][] = array('customer' => '1', 'product' => '2', 'product_quantity' => '3', 'product_image' => '4');
                }
            }

            //print_r($order_products);
            //die;

            //print_r($this->supplier_order->orders);
            if(count($order_customers) > 0)
            {
                $this->smarty->assign(array(
                        'suppliers_customers' => $order_customers,
                        'suppliers_products' => $order_products
                ));
                return $this->smarty->fetch(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'supplierreports/custom_template_content.tpl');
            }else{
                return $this->smarty->fetch(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'supplierreports/custom_template_empty.tpl');
            }
}

public function getFilename()
{
    return 'custom_pdf.pdf';
}
/**
 * Returns the template filename when using bulk rendering
 * @return string filename
 */
public function getBulkFilename()
{
    return 'custom_pdf.pdf';
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a object to call the non-static method of that class,

```
$linkObj = new Link();
$product_image = $linkObj->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite[1], (int)$images[0]['id_image'], 'large_default');
```

More faster way,

```
(new Link)->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite[1], (int)$images[0]['id_image'],    
                        'large_default'); // PHP version >  5.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `static` keyword before `function` in such method declaration and call it statically as much as you wish.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

To call instance method you first should instantiate class with `new` keyword.

If you using `$this` inside method you definitely sholud get class instance first.

```
$link = new Link();

$product_image = $link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite[1], (int)$images[0]['id_image'], 'large_default');
```

If you are not using `$this`, you can freely declare method as static.

Comment: This won't work if that method references `$this` inside of it